# How do I use $location.state()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do the equivalent of

`windows.history.pushState({data: $scope.index}, "", "/winner");`

`$location.state({data: $scope.index})` works but not quite what i want.

Comment: or is `$location.state({data: $scope.index}).path('/winner')` what I want?

Answer (score 1):

`$location.state({data: $scope.index}).path('/winner')`

Comment: You should always include some explanation with your answer

Answer (score 1):

`$location` has a `path` method which lets you change the path, so you can do `$location.path('/winner')`. Its methods are also chainable, so you can combine the state and the path as follows:

```
$location
  .state({data: $scope.index})
  .path('/winner')
```